What is the difference between "statutory instruments" and "ministerial directions"?
This legislation is in the series of "ministerial directions"
The Exception from the Duty to Publish (Department for Business and Trade) (No. 1) Direction 2023
It is no. 1 in the series of ministerial directions.
This series is separate from other delegated legislation, mostly in the form of "statutory instruments".
Other legislation with "directions" in the name is classified as a statutory instrument. For example: The Traffic Signs Regulations and General Directions 2016.
What is the difference between these two pieces of legislation in how they were classified?

The directions in your first link are an instruction to a particular individual, while those in your second link are more general.  Whoever drafted the two pieces of legislation chose different methods and descriptions.

Another example: Income Tax Act 2007, Section 1006 envisages regulations and guidelines related to what counts as research and development for tax credits; the regulations are a statutory instrument and the guidelines are not, even though the regulations in effect say "read the guidelines".

Broadly speaking, a Ministerial Direction (MDs) is a written instruction from a minister to a civil servant or to a government department. It is not a statutory instrument, and so does not constitute legislation.
The normal usage of an MD is described by a Commons Library briefing paper like this:

If a UK Government Minister decides to instruct a Departmental Accounting Officer (a senior civil servant) to proceed with spending, contrary to the advice which has been given by the Accounting Officer, the written instruction is called a ministerial direction.

The list of all such MDs shows that they are normally in the form of a letter from a minister to a civil servant (example).
However, the specific MD mentioned in the question is not an MD of this type, and (at the time of writing) appears to be unique, being the only one listed on legislation.gov.uk. This may be because the power to make MDs are not normally specified in legislation, but are a normal part of intra-departmental communication.
In this case, the MD is still an instruction from a minister to a civil servant - in this case the King's Printer (an office held by the Controller of His Majesty's Stationery Office) - but the power to do is specified in the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018.
It may be that the power to make this unique kind of MD is specified in legislation because it relieves the King's Printer of a statutory duty (in this case, it removes a legal requirement to publish certain EU legislation), which is not true of normal MDs. Equally, it may have been kept as an MD, and not an SI, because it again remains a matter of communication within government, for which an SI is not necessary.

The description

There are three main types of UK Statutory Instrument: 'Orders', 'Regulations', 'Rules'. However, there is no limit imposed on the descriptions that may be given to Statutory Instruments. Other examples include 'Scheme', 'Direction' and 'Declaration'. Different types of instruments serve different functions, but they all have the same legislative force.


Right. But then why is this direction (The Exception from the Duty to Publish (Department for Business and Trade) (No. 1) Direction 2023) not published as a SI?

@nullmatrix876 Because the lawmaker sought that other term was better. Please read the last sentence: Different types of instruments serve different functions, but they all have the same legislative force.

This direction is not a statutory instrument, so that does not apply.
If it were a statutory instrument then it would be in the statutory instrument list, but it is not.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministerial_order#United_Kingdom
In 1992, there was a unique situation which created the need for a "ministerial order" - which was distinct from a statutory instrument. My question is about why a new category was created for this case with this direction.

A statutory instrument is needed if a primary legislation (Acts of Parliament) says that a power is to be exercised by statutory instrument. Statutory instruments are subject to Statutory Instruments Act 1946.
Acts of Parliament may require that directions be given in the form of statutory instruments, for example, the Road Traffic Regulation Act 1984. As a result, the Traffic Signs Regulations and General Directions 2016 are published as an SI.
The particular power granted to the Minister in the Schedule 5 of the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018 does not require a statutory instrument to be issued. However, it requires the publication of such direction, so a separate series was created.
